# Amount input like at PayPal in Flutter

Tags: paypal, dart, flutter, textfield, text-formatting

How is it possible to create a TextField which formats amounts like in PayPal so that the entered number gets added to the right and moves to the left?

For example, pressing `1` should display `0,01` instead of `1`. Followed by a `2` should result in `0,12`. And when deleting, it should do the same thing just in the other direction so that `0,12` becomes `0,01`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Its not too readable but works:

```
TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: (str){
                String newVal;
                if(lastState.length<str.length){
                  String newChar = str.substring(str.length-1).trim();
                  int valueToAdd = int.parse(newChar);
                  int current = int.parse(lastState.replaceAll(r",", ""));
                  newVal = (current*10+valueToAdd).toString();
                } else
                if(lastState.length>str.length){
                  int currentValue = int.parse(lastState.replaceAll(r",", ""));
                  newVal = (currentValue ~/ 10).toString();
                }
                if(newVal.length<3){
                  int x = 3-newVal.length;
                  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
                    newVal = "0$newVal";
                  }
                }
                lastState = newVal.replaceRange(newVal.length-2, newVal.length, ",${newVal.substring(newVal.length-2)}");
                setState(() {
                  controller.text = lastState;
                });
              },
            ),
```

In your class extending `State` add :

```
String lastState = "0,00";
TextEditingController controller;
```

and inside your `initState()` method add this line:

```
controller = new TextEditingController(text: "0,00");
```

Comment: You should put `controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));` in the last setState() Function, otherwise it can give bumps on android. Also consider putting `cursorWidth: 0` to the TextField to make it look cooler.

Comment: @ValentinSeehausen I wrote this code so long ago that I don't even remember what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will work.

```
TextField(keyboardType:
      TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: false, decimal: false),
      controller: _controller,
      onChanged : (value){
      setState((){

      value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\D"), "");
      switch (value.length){
      case 0:
      _controller.text = "0,00";
      _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 4);
      break;
     case 1:
    _controller.text = "0,0${value}";
    _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 3);
    case 2:
    _controller.text = "0,${value}";
    _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 2);
   case 3:
   _controller.text = "${value.subString(0,1)},${value.subString(1,3)}";
   _controller.selection = TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0);
     }

   });

   }

     ),
```